# Как организовать базовый репозиторий в Git?

Tags: git, каркас

Есть репозиторий *repA*, который хранит базовый каркас. И есть репозитории *repB* и *repC*, которые используют *repA* как основу (каркас), и добавляют уже свои модули и прочее.

Как сделать так, чтобы изменения базового каркаса из *repA* попадали в *repB*, *repC*?

Варианты:

1. сделать `git checkout add base git@url.git`, и при `git pull` получать обновления и базового репозитория.
2. Возможно, могут как-то помочь *subtree* или *gitmodules*. Но пока не знаю как.

Comment: Да, но тот же gitmodules сохраняются не в корне repB, а в папке repA (rename). А в корень не поместить субмодуль репозитория.

Comment: а что, `git pull` недостаточно?

Comment: да думал существует более правильный подход для таких случаев

Comment: для простого вливания изменений из другого репозитория в свой сложно придумать более «правильную» команду, нежели `pull`.

Comment: ок, спасибо. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если *b* и *c* были когда-то склонированы из репозитория *a* (возможно, с промежуточными звеньями), то самый простой и «прямой» путь «подтянуть» из него изменения — это использовать команду `pull`.

не обязательно даже, чтобы этот репозиторий был прописан в качестве *remote*:

```
$ git pull адрес.репозитория [ветка.из.него]
```